# Changing pre-trained networks like ResNet-50 from fully connected output layer to convolution layer

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, convolution, pre-trained-model

I am studying image colorization like this paper (http://iizuka.cs.tsukuba.ac.jp/projects/colorization/en/). We know some famous pre-trained networks such as ResNet-50 and GoogLeNet are for classification. Those pre-trained networks use a fully connected layer in the output layer.

I was wondering is it possible to change the last output layers from those pre-trained networks into a convolution output layer?  Therefore, I can apply the pre-trained networks to image colorization. Any recommended frameworks? I currently study Pytorch to try to construct the netwroks.